# Derive operators from a "base" operator - Speed penalty

Tags: c++, performance, operator-keyword

My professor stated, that one could derive "all" operators for an iterator from a single "base" operator without a speed penalty due to inlining.

He stated:

```
// To implement ==, != , >, <, >=, <= only only a few cases based on attrbiutes are required
// a == b       ==      !(a>b)&&!(a<b)
// a != b       ==      !(a==b)
// a < b        ==      Implemented as "actual" operator
// a > b        ==      b < a //Argument swap!
// a >= b       ==      a > b || a == b
// a <= b       ==      a < b || a == b
```

would not introduce a speed penalty when compared to:

```
// To implement ==, != , >, <, >=, <= only only a few cases based on attrbiutes are required
// a == b       ==      Implemented as "actual" operator
// a != b       ==      !(a==b)
// a < b        ==      Implemented as "actual" operator
// a > b        ==      Implemented as "actual" operator
// a >= b       ==      !(a < b )
// a <= b       ==      !(a > b )
```

I get, that "inlining" avoids function calls and the associated overhead in instructions and memory.

But, I am somewhat sure - **This is the question** - that evaluating a dynamic logic statement a la `a && b && c` (e.g) can not be optimized and first a, then b and then c will get evaluated (evaluation is stopped, as soon as a single statement is false).

So, `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` requires the "<-code" to be called twice at worst case.
In my intuition, this is - besides code reuse - a worse implementation, as a speed penalty can occure when compared to "directly" implementing the "==" operator.

**It is not about beeing right or wrong - I want to understand why he is correct**

Comment: how else would you implment something like `a && b && c` ?

Comment: `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` typo? The usual equivalence uses only `<` via `!(b<a)&&!(a<b)`

Comment: how is your question about boolean operator shortcircuiting related to the first part  about writing operators in function of others?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's about "implementing" the == operator as (a>b)&&!(a<b) and the > operator as b < a - which for me means, that the (a>b) is evualted (calling > code) and then (a<b) is evaluated (calling > code) - therefore > code is called two times. In my opinion, implementing == "commonly" could be faster.

Comment: you seem to mix up certain aspects. For example implementing `a == b` as `!(b<a)&&!(a<b)` is not so much about speed, but rather about only defining `a<b` and all the other implementations then trivially follow from that one operator.

Comment: Ask your professor what they mean by "all operators for an iterator". I would hope they mean "all the operators an iterator should have" not "every operator in C++"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I get that "re-use aspect". But doesn't i come with a speed penalty, as in some cases more code has to be executed when compared to a "direct/common" implementation of the specific operator?

Comment: Also, you should tell your professor about the [three-way comparison (aka spaceship) operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) in C++20.

Comment: It is possible to have a standard-conforming C++ implementation where `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` is slower than `a == b`.

Comment: I think when they said that there would be no performance penalty beause of inlining they only refered to the function calls. equivalence `!(b <a) && !(a<b)` can require more comparisons than equality `a == b` does, but in general equivalence is not the same as equality.

Comment: The point is that it is a much weaker requirment on a type that it must have a `operator<` rather than requiring that it must have `operator<` and `operator>` and `operator==` and `operator!=` and `operator<=` and `operator>=`. You only need `operator<` to infer all the others.

Comment: Just to add a slightly different take on this. The above method of implementing one operator in terms of the others is not a good solution. The most important thing about code is it should be readable and maintainable, and should do the correct thing. The second most important thing is performance. The above solution offers neither of these things. I don't personally subscribe to the "Clean Code" meme, but the above code is unreadable. If someone submitted this to me in a PR I would immediately reject it without investing any of my time to understand whether it works or not.

Comment: `&&` is not short-circuited *only if it is overloaded*. Overloading `!`, `!=`, `==` or any other operator doesn't affect this.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant So you would go and implement every operator for it self without "re-using" others? Your decision is based on: Readability and maintainability. Correct?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Typically one would implement something half-way between the two extremes. In other words, not equal should be "not equal". In other words, you define `!=` in terms of `! operator==()`. For less than or equal, this would be "not greater than", as another example.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent If you're not familiar with the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle, in short it is this: You implement greater than as not equal or less than (for example) because the code for both of these is identical but inverted. It is also easy to understand. As others have pointed out, equality and ordering are actually two different concepts. So you should never be implementing an equal/not equal operator in terms of an ordering comparison operator. Also, in the example from the question, I have no intuitive idea what `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` does. Nobody does.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant That's a bold generalization. `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` looks pretty intuitive to me: `a` is neither greater nor less than `b`. They are equivalent. But sure, in this particular case, implementing both `==` and `<` is a good idea. Or, in C++20, defining `operator<=>`.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` is how `std::map<K, V>` defines equality of keys

Comment: @Caleth its not equality. `std::map` determines whether two keys are equivalent. `a` and `b` can be equivalent when `a != b` (sure its nitpicking but confusing equivalence and equality leads to more confusion)

Answer (score 5):

Your question seems to be mostly about implementing `a==b` as `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)`. However, the two represent slightly different concepts: equality and [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). In a lot of situations, the two are the same, but that is not always the case.

If equality and equivalence are the same for this particular datatype, then you are correct that `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)` (with `a>b` implemented as `b<a`) can require two potentially inlined calls to the `<` operator. However, what makes you so sure that two calls to the `<` operator takes more time than one call to the `==` operator? It all depends on the datatype, and you can certainly craft a class for which `operator==` is very slow compared to `operator<`.

So, let's say that the type of `a` and `b` is a thin wrapper around `int` (so the operators aren't already defined). Well, there are two more things to consider. First, the compiler can generate machine code that is wildly different from what you wrote. It can make use of many optimizations, and unless you look at that generated assembly code, you cannot precisely tell how performant a piece of code is. Second, in modern processors, with [pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining) and other complex hardware systems, you cannot really predict performance from the number of instructions alone.

In conclusion, while you might say that, for a simple datatype, a "direct" implementation of `a==b` will not be slower than an implementation as `!(a>b)&&!(a<b)`, you cannot really say that it will be faster. And if it is, it may very well be marginally so.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. So in general: Code-Reuse beats "the anticipated small performance improvements" and optimization for performance is done on a selective basis.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent More or less. A good rule of thumb is to write readable, maintainable code, and optimize only when it's easy or necessary, after measuring (benchmarking). Most of the time, a process will have a single performance bottleneck, so you can improve that specific part to drastically speed it up. No need to touch any other part without knowing exaclty how it impacts performance.

Answer (score 4):

A C++ implementation does not have to emit machine instructions that exactly correspond to the expression you wrote, just ones that have the same observable behaviour.

E.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/h4bfPe9dP) shows them all being implemented by `cmp` and interrogating the flags

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what Compiler Explorer was made for.

https://godbolt.org/z/9rfxKj1WY

Implemented with `!(>)&&!(<)`:

```
struct Int1
{
    int i;
};

bool operator<(Int1 const & lhs, Int1 const & rhs)
{
    return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}

bool operator>(Int1 const & lhs, Int1 const & rhs)
{
    return lhs.i > rhs.i;
}

bool operator==(Int1 const & lhs, Int1 const & rhs)
{
    return !(lhs>rhs) && !(lhs<rhs);
}
```

Implemented with `==`:

```
struct Int2
{
    int i;
};

bool operator==(Int2 const & lhs, Int2 const & rhs)
{
    return lhs.i == rhs.i;
}
```

The resulting assembly, on gcc 13.1 -O3:

```
operator==(Int1 const&, Int1 const&):
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
    sete    al
    ret
operator==(Int2 const&, Int2 const&):
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
    sete    al
    ret
```

The two operators compile to the same assembly*

Note that this is true here only because, for integers, "equal" is the same as "equivalent" - you can have types where this isn't true.

(Though, for some reason, they use `rsi` and `rdi` in opposite order? Makes no difference, still kind of weird to me)